# SQL Server Partition Switching

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to implement Partition Switching in SQL Server 2012.  When I try to switch partitions I get the following error message: "The table  is partitioned while 
index '_PK' is not partitioned.".  I have a clustered index (auto-incremented integer) which is not the primary key on the partition that I am trying to switch to a different table.  The Primary Key is a GUID.  How do I get around this?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the message? Did you look up the requirements for SWITCH? You don't meet them.

Comment: Yes I understand the message.  It's saying the primary key is not partitioned.  I don't want to partition the primary key because it is a guid.  I have a unique clustered index (integer) on the partition.

Comment: So what's the issue? You simply cannot use SWITCH. Move the data manually, or adhere to the requirements that SWITCH demands.

Comment: It's not telling you to partition your GUID in your PK. It is telling you that the index has to be partitioned meaning that it is built on the partition function.

Comment: Your question would be improved by providing your table, index, partition function and partition schema definitions